# how to make any text in richtext box as hyperlink

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am having text in rich text box separated with ';' I want to make every value as hyperlink which is separated with 
';'.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the article here. It shows how to enable hyperlinks in a richtext box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx

1. To link to a Web page with the RichTextBox control
2. Set the Text property to a string that includes a valid URL (for example, "http://www.microsoft.com/").
3. Make sure the DetectUrls property is set to true (the default).
4. Create a new global instance of the Process object.
5. Write an event handler for the LinkClicked event that sends the browser the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have many URLs in rich textbox but they are not shown as links?

Check the `DetectUrls` property to true.

Comment: Nopes I want to make the text as links which are separated by ';'

Answer (score 0):

If you have **arbitrary** text that should be converted to links take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox

To react to user interaction with such a link, as already posted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx